# Merging two branches in both directions in mercurial

Tags: merge, mercurial

I would like to support the following situation:

- development happens on two branches - they are both a bit like "default" (actual development happens on feature branches, but they are branched of and merged to one of these two branches)
- I would like to merge changes from one branch to another in both directions without grafting individual commits
- branches have a diff (on big merge of a feature branch) that I would like to always keep and support

I tried to do a dummy merge as described [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Keep_.22My.22_or_.22Their.22_files_when_doing_a_merge), first in one direction, then after several successful merges, in another direction (dummy merge of dummy merge). Now I need to do a merge again in another direction, and here another dummy merge (of dummy merge of dummy merge) does not help me any more (and I hoped that one dummy merge would be enough anyway).

Is it possible to do development in this fashion, or is it better to do most of development in one branch? (well, I know it is better for hg, but I have reasons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preface**

If both branches share the same functionality (unstable common DEVEL), I can't see any reasons in such splitting, except added headache

**Face**

You can avoid merging unwanted changeset from one branch into another **and** use *ordinary* merge if you'll convert this mergeset into MQ-patch ( or maybe [shelveset](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ShelveExtension)) and always merge from|to (read ["Merging patches with new upstream revisions"](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension#Merging_patches_with_new_upstream_revisions) for merging to branch hint) branch with unapplied patch

Comment: Thank you for the links - now I see that possible solutions are not as convenient as I hoped, so I think I should really avoid doing what I described in the question :)

Comment: @KonstantinLopuhin - JFYI, in my old case (common  core with two diverged permanent changes) I ended with "one branch - two independent MQ-patches on top of vanilla" in order to avoid headache and merges (I'm too lazy) around `hg qpop -a` + `hg qpush --move` dance